# What is the difference between problem solving and theorem proving?Is mathematics problem solving or theorem proving?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Some books of permutation and combinations ,theorems are to proved while in some book problem is to be solved using logic.

Comment: both are the same things.

Comment: Seems better suited to [math.se].

Answer (score 1):

In school, your problems are often pre-cooked exercises in which you are supposed to apply theorems or maybe prove them.

In the real world, you may encounter problems that you have no idea how to find adequate mathematical representations for, or whether such representations exist at all. Mathematical representations are abstractions: they simplify by leaving out detail, so you need to be able to simplify such that some important essence you want to reason about is captured without oversimplifying and distorting what is really going on. This can be more challenging than the subsequent work of applying or proving theorems in the representation you've chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solving is the art of finding the solution(s) from a problem statement. Theorem proving is the art of showing that a known solution is indisputably correct.

But if the given problem is to craft a proof, then theorem proving is an instance of problem solving. :-)